# How to get the values from XML tags to Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am inexperienced in vba coding, got a requirement to pull the values from the xml file to excel sheet. Tried to code with the help of google, but not succeeded. Below is my xml file

```
<CRD>
..
<PLAN>Plan01</PLAN>
..
</CRD>
```

Below are My tested codes :

Code 1

```
Private Sub RunTest_Click()

Dim envFrmwrkPath As String
Dim objfso, app, Eval As Object

envFrmwrkPath = ActiveSheet.Range("E6").Value

Set EnvVarXML = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

EnvVarXML.Load (envFrmwrkPath & "CRD-0071709[1].xml")

For Each UIElement In EnvVarXML.SelectNodes("//CRD")
Set Field = Eval(objUIElement.SelectSingleNode("PLAN").Text)
Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = Field
Next

End Sub
```

Code 2

```
Sub ImportXMLtoList()

Dim xml_doc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim onode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim chnode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim brtn As Boolean

brtn = xml_doc.Load("D:\Satheesh 244688\CI Team\Med D Formulary Testing\May 8th\CRD-0071709[1].xml")

'Set onode = xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("/CRD")

For Each onode In xml_doc.SelectSingleNode("//CRD")

nm = onode.nodeName
If nm = "RxPlanID" Then
Sheet1.Cells(2, 2) = chnode.Text
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear if the xml you will be using is as above or if you will be looping through multiple nodes.

Using the xml below

```
<Root>
<Row>
<Name>John</Name>
</Row>
<Row>
<Name>Anne</Name>
</Row>
</Root>
```

and this vba

```
Sub GetXML()
    Dim myXML As Object
    Dim myNodes As Object
    Dim myNode As Object
    Dim myRow As Integer

    'Create xml object
    Set myXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

    myXML.Load "c:\data.xml"     'Change for your file path

    'Check if valid XML
    If myXML.parseError <> 0 Then
        'Parse error, so show message
        MsgBox "Something went wrong loading XML!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & myXML.parseError.reason
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set myNodes = myXML.SelectNodes("//Row")
    myRow = 1
    For Each myNode In myNodes
        Sheet1.Cells(myRow, 1) = myNode.SelectSingleNode("Name").Text
        myRow = myRow + 1
    Next myNode


End Sub
```

Puts "John" in cell A1 and "Anne" in cell A2 on Sheet1